# Update related properties in response to observable change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Update**

My original post is pretty long - here's the tl;dr version:

*How do you update all properties of a knockout model after a single property has changed?  The update function must reference an observableArray in the viewModel.*

-- More details --

I'm using KnockoutJS.  I have a Zoo and a Tapir model and three observables in the viewmodel - zoos, tapirCatalog and currentTapir.  The tapirCatalog is populated from the server and the currentTapir holds the value of whichever tapir is being edited at the time.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:  A user has added a tapir from a list of tapirs to his/her zoo.  When viewing the zoo, the user can edit a tapir and replace it with another.  To do this a popup window is shown with a select form populated by tapir names and a span showing the currently selected GoofinessLevel.

So, when the select element changes this changes the TapirId in currentTapir.  I want that to trigger something that changes the currentTapir's Name and GoofinessLevel.

I tried subscribing to currentTapir().GoofinessLevel but cannot get it to trigger:

```
function Zoo(data) {
    this.ZooId = ko.observable(data.ZooId);
    this.Tapirs = ko.observableArray(data.Tapirs);
}

function Tapir(data) {
    this.TapirId = ko.observable(data.TapirId);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.GoofinessLevel = ko.observable(data.Name);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Initializer, because I get an UncaughtType error because TapirId is undefined when attempting to subscribe to it
    var tapirInitializer = { TapirId: 0, Name: "Template", GoofinessLevel: 0 }

    self.zoos = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.tapirCatalog = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.currentTapir = ko.observable(new Tapir(tapirInitializer));

    self.currentTapir().TapirId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        console.log("TapirId changed to: " + newValue);
    }); // This does not show in console when select element is changed
};
```

Oddly enough, when I subscribe to the Goofiness level inside the Tapir model I get the trigger:

```
function Tapir(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.TapirId = ko.observable(data.TapirId);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.GoofinessLevel = ko.observable(data.Name);

    self.TapirId.subscribe(function (newId) {
        console.log("new TapirId from internal: " + newId);
    }); // This shows up in the console when select element is changed
}
```

I suspect that this is a pretty common scenario for people using KO but I haven't be able to find anything.  And I've searched for a while now (it's possible that I may not have the correct vocabulary to search with?).  I did find this solution, but he references the viewmodel from the model itself -- which seems like back coding since I would think the Tapir should not have any knowledge of the Zoo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QREf3/

** Update **
Here's the code for my select element (the parent div has `data-bind="with: currentTapir"`:

```
<select
    data-bind="attr: { id: 'tapirName', name: 'TapirId' },
        options: $root.tapirCatalog,
        optionsText: 'Name',
        optionsValue: 'TapirId',
        value: TapirId">
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the value property to be the currentTapir observable? That way the whole observable is swapped out when a new one is selected and not just the Id

Comment: @AndrewWalters That is a much better way of going about it.  Haha, so simple.

Comment: And, for more information about doing this: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need to do is bind the select to an observable instead of the Id

```
<select
    data-bind="attr: { id: 'tapirName', name: 'TapirId' },
        options: $root.tapirCatalog,
        optionsText: 'Name',
        optionsValue: 'TapirId',
        value: currentTapir">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  That accomplished what I needed done.  I should mention that I needed to remove optionsValue to get it to work.  I am still curious on how this might be done manually, but I'm happy leaving that question for a different time.